# Question about backup and restores

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, central-administration, backup, restore

I'm getting ready to backup my dev server and restore what i need on my production server for the first time. What I want to know is if I do a backup/restore  in the future to add updates and modules to the production server will the restore overwrite the content that has been add to the on the production server?

We want to release our site in parts. It consist roughly of 5-6 parts. So we want to do is release one part, populate it with data, add another, start filling that up and so on. At this point i'm just looking for a way that would could deploy our site like this. Any thoughts?

Note: I'm running SharePoint 2013.

Comment: I assume your need is to add new features to the production site once your dev activities are done . Backup and Restore overwrites the site so whatever content that is earlier is gone so please take caution and planning before your proceed with that . Planning based on what type of site is yours.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend backup/restore as a way of doing deployment in SharePoint.

Depending on the type of development which has been done it might work the first time (It it's all content and within the same AD (which should be avoided)). But after that you can't deploy that way.

Comment: I was reading something taking about a sandbox solution to do updates. I'm not sure if that could work or how to do it. Essentially my company is just starting development for it's first internal sharepoint site. We want to release our site in parts. It consist roughly of 5-6 parts. So we want to do is release one part, populate it with data, add another, start filling that up and so on. At this point i'm just looking for a way that would could deploy our site like this. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about the content that will be added to your production site while you work on the rest of the parts ?